Leaflet - setMaxBounds for images with different resolutions
I'm trying to create a map with raster images using Leaflet's TileLayer and CRS.Simple projection. I want to be able to switch between two images with different resolutions:

Image one: 5120 x 3840
Image two: 2560 x 1920

I used gdal2tiles to create tiles out of those images with zoom levels 2-7.
I extended the CRS projection to flip the y axis:
const CRSPixel = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
  transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 0, 1, 0),
});

Where I'm completely lost is when setting the map boundaries, so the user cannot drag outside of the map. I'm using the following approach:
const southWest = map.unproject([0, image.height], image.nativeZoom);
const northEast = map.unproject([image.width, 0], image.nativeZoom);

const bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

What I can't wrap my head around is the 2nd argument of the map.unproject's method (image.nativeZoom) and why it's 5 for the 1st image and 4 for the 2nd image to obtain the correct boundaries. I initially thought it's supposed to be the maxZoom, which is 7 for both tileLayers, but that value totally messes up the boundaries for both.
So my question is: What is that number, why is it different for both layers and how to compute it?
Or perhaps I'm missing something else?
I created the following fiddle to demonstrate the issue. The "zoom" value sent to map.unproject to compute the bounds is stored in nativeZoom property. I also created two markers at the southWest and northEast coordinates which you can see when you fully unzoom the map:
https://jsfiddle.net/matejm/aqbex679/latest
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cross posting: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/487794/leaflet-setmaxbounds-for-images-with-different-resolutions
